# Extjs grid Filter

Tags: extjs, filter, grid

I am filter on a grid and I am trying to run the filter on it. I want o run the filter from code when a user selects a value from a drop down else where in the page.

I see that grid.getFilter('dataIndex').setActive(true) is setting the filter active but i am not sure how to set the value. There is a methid called setValue() but it is a private methos. Is there any way i could do it.

Thanks,
SS

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the grid's store easily..

`grid.getStore().filter('field', 'valueToSearchFor');`

Comment: yes it is possible to filter the store, but my grid uses paging, so what you have mentioned only works for the current page, if you click next or previous int he paging tool bar you will lose filtering. Using  Gridfilter plugin I can persist the results. But I can do that only through user interface by clicking on the column and entering the value in the plugin field. My question is How do I do the same programatically? thanks

Answer (score 0):

`PagingToolbar` may be just what you are looking for.  Alternatively, I've come across cases where I could set the filtration params as baseParams and then blow that out when I'm done with it.